# Add row in Material Table on button click from outside material table in react js

Tags: material-table

How to call add row functionality of the material table when clicking the button from outside of the material table

[Add new row in the material table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUyTK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Import `import { forwardRef } from "react";`

Call
`const addActionRef = React.useRef();`

Include this code in the place u want ur button. I am using material ui button here

```
<Button
  color="primary"
  variant="contained"
  onClick={() => addActionRef.current.click()}  //The line you need 
>
  Add new item
</Button>
```

and override the action in material table

```js
components = {
  {
    Action: props => {
      //If isn't the add action
      if (typeof props.action === typeof Function || props.action.tooltip !== 'Add') {
        return <MTableAction { ...props
        }
        />
      } else {
        return <div ref = {
          addActionRef
        }
        onClick = {
          props.action.onClick
        }
        />;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If u have any question please ask.
I have used here react js with material ui.

https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2133

This link might help u.... this is from where I got the answer